# Работа с файлами в Си: как вывести переменные из файла?

Tags: c, файлы

Задание требует вывести переменные числового типа, из ini-файла(или txt), где в столбец записаны числа.  Вот моя реализация, но переменные невозможно использовать в матфункциях.
Как сделать тоже, но с выводом переменных типа int или float?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
FILE * data;
data = fopen("New_File.ini","r");

int n, k, p, y;

fscanf(data, "%s %s %s", &n, &k, &p);

y=p*p;
printf("%s \n%s \n%s \n%s \n", &n, &k, &p, &y);

fclose(data);
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно выводить значения переменных, а не их адреса. Поэтому

     fscanf(data, "%d %d %d", &n, &k, &p);

но

     printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%s\n", &n, &k, &p, &y);


И вводить/выводить не по формату %s (что в данном случае -- грубая ошибка)

Comment: А какую книгу по Си вы читали? Возьмите другую, эта не помогает.

Comment: @alexlz, амперсанды в `printf` уберите, плиз )))

Comment: @mikillskegg виноват. Написать -- написал, а убрать забыл. Склероз подвёл. Конечно же

      printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", n, k, p, y);

Answer (score 1):

Вот немного подправил Ваш код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
  FILE * data;
  data = fopen("New_File.ini", "r");
  int n, k, p;
  fscanf(data, "%d %d %d", &n, &k, &p);
  int y = p * p;
  printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", n, k, p, y);
  fclose(data);
}
```

Протестировал, всё работает.